# syslog to a different location for each site than on /var/log/syslog

Tags: 7, log-messages

We have many sites on our server and we are hoping that we can save syslogs of each site on the root of each site than all logs being dumped on /var/log/syslog

Is it possible?

For example, logs for each site would be on /srv/site_name/sitelog?

Many Thanks!

Comment: You can configure syslog file location in server configuration file for each site.